# How to upgrade libstdc++

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, c++

I have the same question as [How do I get my DEB to install libstdc++.so.6.0.20?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546994/how-do-i-get-my-deb-to-install-libstdc-so-6-0-20). (more or less).  The developer of the binary I downloaded used a later version libstdc++ than is present on my 14.04LTS.  Can I manually upgrade to libstdc++.so.6.0.20?  Would I need to upgrade the compiler, too?  Would that mess up other parts of my system?

He promised to recompile using the previous compiler version, thereby working with my library but never followed through.

(I don't have his source.)

https://github.com/FoldingAtHome/fah-client-pub/issues/1147

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting + installing gcc/g++ 4.9 on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/428198/getting-installing-gcc-g-4-9-on-ubuntu)